# Display product attribute value if any grouped products have a particular attribute value on a grouped products view that are shown?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, frontend, grouped-products

I was wondering how I could grab a custom attribute lets say "has_lowprice" and pass this along to a grouped product page.

What I'm doing on my product pages is grabbing this attribute and displaying information if this product has a certain attribute.

```
<div id="lowPrice" data-type="<?php print $_product->gethas_lowprice(); ?>"></div>
```

The above code will display the "has_lowprice" attribute.

What I need to know is how to pass this on to a grouped product page if any of the products on the page have this has_lowprice attribute.

Thanks for any help on this matter.

Comment: Are you trying to display attribute only, if your product type is grouped?

Comment: I have a list of products that are being displayed on a grouped product listing page. The above code works great on single products as it knows how to query the product being displayed to get the correct attribute of has_lowprice.

Comment: I need to grab this attribute and display it if ANY of the grouped products have this attribute with any value. Basically this is a custom attribute with an 1 or 0 being the value. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve the collection using the following

```
$_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProductCollection($_product)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
    ->setPositionOrder()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('has_lowprice', 1);
```

On a side note, please add this to a custom block class, not the phtml file for best practice.